# Swift: get number of values in an enum? Goal is to avoid hard coding number in random function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, enums

Given the code below, is it possible in Swift to programmatically determine the number of values inside an enum? The goal is to avoid hard coding a number in order to randomly choose a type of this enum.

```
enum Direction: Int {
    case North
    case East
    case South
    case West
    case Northeast
    case Southeast
    case Southwest
    case Northwest

    static func random() -> Direction {
        return Direction(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(8)) + 1)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using the rawValue of the final element?